# Routing in MVVM android (Best practice)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I use the MVVM pattern. I was wondering how other programmers do routing between screens.

It could be done like this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val routeState = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        //more fun 
        //...
        //...
        routeState.value = "Home"
    }
}

class MyActivity : Activity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
    
    onCreate() {
        //viewModel init 
        
        viewModel.routeState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when(it) {
                "Home" -> {
                    toHome()
                    //finish()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I understand that this approach is bad. So I would like to ask you how you do it?

Comment: recursively go through this comment thread, the linked articles, the other linked comment threads and the articles linked in them https://old.reddit.com/r/android_devs/comments/hby9ru/simplifying_jetpack_navigation_between_toplevel/ lots of stuff to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your routing to be explicit, there are a few steps you need to take:

1.) never have 2 Activities on the task stack at the same time, prefer having 1 Activity for the app, and manage routing internally within that Activity.

2.) you need to consider when the app goes to background, is killed by Android, and is restored. Fragments out of the box are recreated based on their current "added" state, but your `private val currentRoute: MutableLiveData<String>` would be lost across process death unless it is initialized from `savedStateHandle.getLiveData("route")`.

3.) you need to consider that screens have arguments, which can sometimes be more complex than a mere string, unless you start to serialize these "routes" to JSON objects for example, or instead of String you use a Parcelable class.

4.) you need to consider that it's generally invalid to start navigating after `onStop`, so you want to either ignore commands (as Jetpack Navigation does), or enqueue them until after onResume.

5.) you need to consider that navigation can be asynchronous (not immediate), although when you use Fragments you generally don't need to worry about this. Jetpack Navigation for example doesn't really care about this (except in `DynamicNavHostFragment`).

6.) you need to consider that if navigation is asynchronous, then you can get navigation actions while there is navigation in progress. You might want to either guard against this, or enqueue them. Or maybe enqueue them when going forward, but ignore them after going back (to eliminate certain invalid states).

If you take all 6 of this into account, you end up with the library I wrote: https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack

Now your navigation is as simple as

```
class MyViewModel(private val backstack: Backstack) : CustomViewModel() {
    fun toOtherScreen() {
        backstack.goTo(OtherScreen())
    }
}

class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity(), SimpleStateChanger.NavigationHandler {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)

        // ...

        Navigator.configure()
                 .setStateChanger(SimpleStateChanger(this))
                 .install(this, container, History.of(HomeScreen())
    }

     override fun onNavigationEvent(stateChange: StateChange) {
         val screen = stateChange.topNewKey<Any>()
         when {
             screen is HomeScreen -> {
                ...
             }
             screen is OtherScreen -> {
                ...
             }
         }
     }
}

@Parcelize object HomeScreen: Parcelable // i prefer data classes for a stable `toString()`

@Parcelize object OtherScreen: Parcelable // i prefer data classes for a stable `toString()`
```

And that's almost pretty much it, except there's a chance you might want to use Fragment, consult the readme for how to use the `DefaultFragmentStateChanger` instead of the built-in stuff.

---

Okay, so let's assume you didn't buy into my library for whatever reason. Then people nowadays typically use Jetpack Navigation.

In that case, you'd want an Activity-scoped ViewModel that is passed into your ViewModel where the Activity-scoped ViewModel holds a `LiveData<Event<NavigationCommand>>` (assuming you didn't buy into my other lib [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Zhuinden/event-emitter) and use the event wrapper instead), which is observed by the Activity in order to handle navigation triggered from a ViewModel, but navigation state still being managed by the NavController from Jetpack Navigation.

```
class MyViewModel(private val navigationDispatcher: NavigationDispatcher) : ViewModel() {
    fun toOtherScreen() {
        navigationDispatcher.emit { navController ->
            navController.navigate(HomeDirections.toOtherScreen())
        }
    }
}

class MyActivity : Activity() {
    private val navigationDispatcher by viewModels<NavigationDispatcher>()

    private val viewModel by viewModels {
        object: ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T: ViewModel?> create(clazz: Class<T>): T = MyViewModel(navigationDispatcher)
        }
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)            

        navigationDispatcher.navigationCommands.observeEvent(this) { command ->
            command.invoke(Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host))
        }
    }
}

typealias NavigationCommand = (NavController) -> Unit

class NavigationDispatcher: ViewModel() {
    private val navigationEmitter: MutableLiveData<Event<NavigationCommand>> = MutableLiveData()
    val navigationCommands: LiveData<Event<NavigationCommand>> = navigationEmitter

    fun emit(navigationCommand: NavigationCommand) {
        navigationEmitter.value = Event(navigationCommand)
    }
}

class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set

    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    fun peekContent(): T = content
}

class EventObserver<T>(private val onEventUnhandledContent : (T) -> Unit): Observer<Event<T>> {
    override fun onChanged(event: Event<T>?) {
        event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
            onEventUnhandledContent(it)
        }
    }
}

inline fun <T> LiveData<Event<T>>.observeEvent(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    crossinline observer: (T) -> Unit
): Observer<Event<T>> = EventObserver<T> { t -> observer(t) }.also {
    this.observe(lifecycleOwner, it)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Jetpack I really prefer doing navigation via Navigation Component:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

However if I for example click login button, wait for login response and on success I want to navigate to main screen, I would have something like this (ViewModel + Coroutines used in example):

```kotlin
class LoginViewModel(
    private val repository: Repository
): ViewModel() {

    val liveData = MutableLiveData<LoginPayload>()

    fun login(username: String, password: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        liveData.postValue(LoginPayload.StartLoginAction)
        try {
            val response = repository.login(username, password)
            if(response is Success) {
                liveData.postValue(LoginPayload.LoginSuccess)
            } else {
                liveData.postValue(LoginPayload.LoginError)
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            liveData.postValue(LoginPayload.LoginError)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
sealed class LoginPayload {
    object StartLoginAction: LoginPayload()
    object LoginSuccess: LoginPayload()
    object LoginError: LoginPayload()
}
```

```kotlin
class MyActivity : Activity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel
    
    onCreate() {
        //viewModel init 
        
        viewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when(it) {
                LoginPayload.StartLoginAction -> //show progress bar, hide login button
                LoginPayload.LoginError -> //hide progress bar, show error dialog, show login button
                LoginPayload.LoginSuccess -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    findNavController.navigate(R.id.action_login_to_home)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works correctly if the `action` from `login` to `home` is `popToInclusive="true" popUpTo="@id/login"`, otherwise navigating back will immediately trigger navigation forward

Answer (score 2):

there is many way for do this.

One way is to use the same `Observer` or `MutableLiveData` (that you do this)

the other way is use interface :

BaseViewModel :

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<N> : ViewModel() {

private lateinit var mNavigator: WeakReference<N>

fun getNavigator(): N {
    return mNavigator.get()!!
}

fun setNavigator(navigator: N) {
    this.mNavigator = WeakReference(navigator)
}
}
```

viewModel

```
class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel<MyInterFace>() {
 val routeState = MutableLiveData<String>()

 init {
    //  Wherever you need, you can call your functions  :
     getNavigator().test()

 }
}
```

MyInterFace :

```
interface MyInterFace{
   fun test()
  
}
```

Activity :

```
class MyActivity : Activity(),MyInterFace {
   private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

     //  init viewModel
     //    .
     //    .
     //    .
     //  then set navigator 
     viewmodel.setNavigator(this)
    
  }

override fun test(){
   // do somthing....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Routing isn't the responsibility of view model, its the responsibility of Intent in android, and usually devs make a router class which is the wrapper on intent to do navigation between screens,

You can store a logic in ViewModel which decides whether the screen should navigate to different locations or not.

example: splashScreenViewModel can have the logic of isAuthenticated flag which when true routes screen to home, else go to login screen.

So according to your cause its an unnecessary jump from viewmodel to activity then migration to diffrent screen, plus its error-prone because whenever the `routeState.value`  changes navigation to home will trigger. not ideal flow

Comment: `Routing isn't the responsibility of view model,` citation needed. AFAIK the jetpack `ViewModel` represents the scope that belongs to either the screen or a shared flow, and if it belongs to a shared flow, it can definitely know how to go to another flow. Therefore it can have the responsibility of routing.

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce, you bring up a good concept, to answer this I would like to revisit the concept of ViewModel, there's are two strategies used while creating a view model first is having VM having presentation logic of view inside it, which I consider wrong as it makes VM coupled with view, other is making ViewModel expose data that any view can consume which is actually the right way, even if you create a shared ViewModel is contains data that can be shared between view but not anything about flow or currently visible screen.so view model doesn't know about screen or navigation

Answer (score 0):

Rightly put. Routing isn't the responsibility of view model. Thats the role of the framework. In fact my way of dealing it to have navigation as a service which is implemented by the framework(android). Its the ViewModel that can delegate this to the navigator service and thats how the navigation is done. Any other approach would love to hear.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit with a code example. As someone trying to learn the "Android framework" this answer doesn't add any useful insight.